# ASP.Net Core 5.0 Docker - no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am running Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. I have Docker Desktop running which is pointing to Windows containers. I am looking into publishing a ASP.Net Core 5.0 web application using Docker and I get the error

**no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries**

I am using the Dockerfile that Visual Studio creates. This file contains the line

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base`

I have tried changing to these tags but I still get the same error

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803 AS base`

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base`

I don't have the ability to upgrade the Windows version I am using. Am I now unable to publish to Docker?